# Скрипт выключения звука

Tags: wsh

Вечер добрый.

Есть скрипт скрытого открытия IE с заданной страницей/сайтом, но на этой странице/сайте есть звук который слышен при открытии сайта, т.е. сайта не видно, а звук его открытие выдает!

Можно ли выключить звук через скрипт?

```
var WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WSHShell.Run("iexplore", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Крайне мело вероятно, что это получится сделать через WScript.Shell.

[InternetExplorer.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx) Вам в помощь.

[Тут](http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch09c.html) немного о другом, но тем не менее показывает возможности.

Comment: к сожалению не силен в этом многочисленом коде ((( ничего не нашел